# Remove the node that contains the key from the Linked list

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have a remove method , find the element in that list and delete it.That topic is about Doubly linked list.Is my operation true in if and else if statement for the formation of the new list?

```
public void Remove(int key) {//key = number in the list.
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("Empty List..!");
        } else if (key == head.key) {
            head.prev.next = head.next;
            head.next = null;
            noOfNodes--;
        } else if (key == tail.key) {
            tail.next.prev = tail.prev;
            tail.prev = null;
            noOfNodes--;
        } else {
            for (LinkedListNode temp = head; temp.next != null; temp = temp.next) {
                if (temp.key == key) {
                    temp.prev.next = temp.next;
                    temp.next.prev = temp.prev;
                    temp.prev = null;
                    temp.next = null;
                    noOfNodes--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @LawrenceAiello I edited. Sorry about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This might be the issue `tail.next.prev = tail.prev;`. Are you sure `tail.next` is not null? Isn't `tail` the last element of your doubly linked list?

Comment: @ashutosh You are absolutely right. Thanks for your comment. I corrected my code thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it looks like `tail` is the last node of your linked list.

So, this might be the issue `tail.next.prev = tail.prev;`. Since `tail.next` is `null` as `tail` is the last element, when you access `prev` on `tail.next` it throws `NullPointerException`.